# A term for the period of time after terminating a contract

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, phrases

I have a virtual address service that I would like to terminate abruptly. It will take some time to update all the contact points, and there might also be contacts that I forget to inform. I would like to ask the provider, in case there are mails, are they able to keep us informed for **a period of time** after the contract has ended?

Is there a proper term/phrase to describe that ***time period*** or the ***service rendered*** after terminating a service/contract?

Comment: I would be more likely to specify the length of time, eg *would you keep us informed for a month after the contract has ended?*

Comment: As Peter said. Or you could call it a transition period, but there's no guarantee the provider allows such things.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are no  words to represent what you describe because it is a fictional case. There are words to describe what you wish to do.

From what I can understand of your post, What you wish to do is the following

**Terminate your contract**

Use the service,

- but not quite in the same way as before

1. Now you just wish to be informed if any mail arrives
2. presumably you wish to be notified by whom.

Therefore *we could term this as use* **an out of contract; continued service**.

This service will be for a specified period of time after the contract finishes

Therefore *we could term this* as **free service period**

> *After I cancel my contract with yourselves, I will require a free service period of... days where you need to provide an out of contract; continued service.*